# Multiple virtual hosts - How to set up separate directories?

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I bought a 2nd domain and I'm trying to set up a 2nd and separate site on the same ubuntu server.

How do I set up the folders and config files to allow my sites to have separate source files which can't access each other?

My apache2 conf file:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups On
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel notice
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

My ports conf file:

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

My conf file for site 1 (currently working with SSL):

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.com.conf:
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName site1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/public
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1.com/privkey.pem
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

My conf for site 2 (I want to set it up as HTTP for now, I'll set up SSL after confirming that it's working):

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2.com.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
</VirtualHost>
```

I put the 2nd site's config file in /etc/apache2/sites-available and ran a2ensite site2.com.conf, and then ran systemctl reload apache2.

**How do I set it up so that each site only has access to its own directory?**

If I remove these lines from apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then loading site1.com shows Error 403 Forbidden, even though site1.com.conf has this line:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/public
```

I thought of putting a Directory tag in site1.com.conf, but there is already one:

```
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
```

How do I set it up so that both sites can be accessed on their own domain, while neither site can be accessed from a subdirectory of the other?

**EDIT:**

My question is really about the relationship between these 3 things:

1. apache2.conf's "Directory"
2. site 1's "DocumentRoot"
3. site 2's "DocumentRoot"

And how I should set up my directory structure.

Currently they are set like this:

1. /var/www/public
2. /var/www/public
3. /var/www/site2

Right now if I go to site 2 it says 403 forbidden, because site 2's DocumentRoot is outside the main config file's Directory folder. And I don't want to set site 2's DocumentRoot to /var/www/public/site2, because then that will be inside site 1's directory.

So is it necessary to use this configuration?:

1. /var/www/public
2. /var/www/public/site1
3. /var/www/public/site2

And what's the difference between that and something like this:

1. /var/www
2. /var/www/site1
3. /var/www/site2

If there are server-only files in /var/www, can site 1 or site 2 ever access them insecurely (client browsing to them)?

My question is about how exactly to set up the directory structure, and I don't understand the difference between apache2.conf's "Directory" and sites-enabled conf's "DocumentRoot".

Comment: I don't think they have access to each others files, as long as you don't create symbolic links and tell Apache to follow them.

Comment: It looks like your configuration is already correct. If you think it's not correct, can you show us an example of something that works that shouldn't?

Comment: @MosheKatz I edited it to show my issue, I'm just confused about how to set up the directory structure

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little tour of the Apache configuration to start:

### `<Directory /some/path/to/somewhere>`

`<Directory ...>` is an XML-style tag that starts a section of the configuration. It ends with `</Directory>`. In between those two tags, everything applies to the directory shown in the opening tag. Apache calls these "sections".

In your example, you have a few `<Directory>` sections:

- `<Directory />` - This section covers absolutely everything in your filesystem ***unless overridden in a more specific tag***. The most important item here is `Require all denied`. This prevents Apache from accessing everything on your hard drive.
- `<Directory /var/www/public>` - This section covers the directory in which you have your site. The important line here is `Require all granted` which allows Apache to access the files in that directory.

---

### `DocumentRoot /some/path/to/somewhere`

`DocumentRoot` tells Apache where the files for the website are located. Usually you will have it inside a `<VirtualHost>` section, since that is where you want to define your website's settings.

In your example, you have a few `DocumentRoot` directives:

- `DocumentRoot /var/www/public` - this is inside the `<VirtualHost>` for your `site1.com`. That means that when a user goes to `site1.com`, Apache should look for content in `/var/www/public`.
- `DocumentRoot /var/www/site2` - this is inside the `<VirtualHost>` for your `site2.com`. That means that when a user goes to `site2.com`, Apache should look for content in `/var/www/site2`.

---

It is important to remember these points:

1. **There is no requirement that `<Directory>` sections be related to `<VirtualHost>` sections, and `<Directory>` has absolutely nothing to do with `DocumentRoot`.**
2. The `DocumentRoot` is the top level of a website. A user who goes to `site1.com` will only be able to see files in `/var/www/public` and a user who goes to `site2.com` will only see files in `/var/www/site2` (unless you have [some kind of security issue](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal) in software that you are hosting, but that's a different discussion). Neither site will be able to see files in `/var/www` since that path is "above" the `DocumentRoot` - that's what "Root" means.

However, even though there is no connection between `DocumentRoot` and `Directory`, the fact is that you still need a `<Directory>` section for each of your sites. (You could also use a single one for all sites, but for now we'll keep it simple and more secure.) The reason for this is the `<Directory />` section mentioned above which blocks access to everywhere by default and forces you to explicitly grant access to other directories.

---

Now that we've explained the relationship between these two configuration items, let's see what you need for your setup:

You have two sites, `site1.com` and `site2.com`. You currently have them in `/var/www/public` and `/var/www/site2` respectively, as set by the `DocumentRoot` directive in each `<VirtualHost>`.

Therefore, in order to permit access to those directories, you also should have two `<Directory>` sections, one for each site. For your purposes, both of their contents can be identical to the current `<Directory /var/www/public>` section that you already have:

```
<Directory /var/www/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/site2>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Separate from those, you need the `DocumentRoot` directives as you originally wrote them.

---

Personally, I would also rename `/var/www/public` to `/var/www/site1` to match the site name. It's much easier to manage if you keep all names the same.